# Visual Studio 2019 Debugging Causes Mouse Lag

Tags: visual-studio, mouse, visual-studio-2019, lag

Dealing with an extremely annoying issue and unable to find a resolution so far around the web.

Issue description:
Using Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition, and after a bit of debugging, stepping through code and inspecting objects in Quick Watch I notice that mouse movement begins to lag. Mouse pointer is still movable but is jumpy, like bad wireless mouse connection. Extremely annoying as I first though wireless mouse was at fault. But the issue goes away immediately after Visual Studio is closed. This is also very reproducible, although does not appear to happen right away, seems to happen after a few debug sessions.

Things I've tried:

- Uninstalled all Visual Studio extensions
- Reset all Visual Studio settings and performed "Repair" from VS Installer
- Disabled Windows Defender, no other anti virus / spyware software is running
- Updated Windows 10 to latest update
- Updated Visual Studio to latest version as of now

If anyone has any suggestions on how to fix this, please share.

If you are experiencing the same issue, please add details about your environment in comments (Visual Studio edition & update version, .NET version of the project, Windows update version).

Comment: What happens if you change the Hardware Acceleration options in VS's UI? Also, do you have discrete graphics (AMD Radeon/NVIDIA) or using on-CPU (Intel HD Graphics)? Do you have many devices attached to your motherboard using PCI-Express lanes (e.g. lots of NVMe SSDs, multiple GPUs, M.2 / U.2 SSDs)?

Answer (score 2):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNbNn.png)

This is mainly caused by hardware acceleration feature which is caused by Graphics Card bugs.

> The Visual Studio team has continued to notice a small but important series of performance and reliability issues that are caused by bugs in the installed graphics drivers. By default, Visual Studio automatically adjusts the visual experience in order to maximize performance and responsiveness across client configurations. Visual Studio also uses hardware graphics acceleration when it is available on the client. For most customers, these Visual Studio default settings provide the best user experience. However, some users have reported that manual adjustments to these settings can result in improved experience. This article describes how to make these adjustments in Visual Studio.

Solution :
Disable "Use hardware graphics acceleration if available" in visual studio settings (Tools -> Environment -> General)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNbNn.png)